# Ordered list with repeated numbers

Tags: html, css, html-lists

If i write the following HTML code:

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ol>
```

I will get

```
1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk
4. Rice
5. Bread
```

What code should i write if I want to have the following result:

```
1. Coffee
2. Tea
2. Milk
4. Rice
5. Bread
```

Something like this would be ok:

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li class="same_number_as_previous">Milk</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be links?

Comment: No, I just want a custom-ordered-list

Comment: Check my code Snippet!!! It's exactly what you want @Thanos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ditch the stock counter and use a custom [CSS2 Counter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters):

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: foo 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: foo 1;
}
ol li.dont-increment {
  counter-increment: foo 0;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(foo) ".";
  /* bells and whistles */
  float: left;
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li class="dont-increment">Milk</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Using logic like that in CSS is always neat.

Comment: There might be a cleaner way than this but to actually skip a number you could counter-increment by more than 1. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4agub91a/ . An option would be to just do this by inline styling during creation.

Answer (score 1):

Is it fine?

```css
ol {
    
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ol>
<ol start=2>
<li>Milk</li>
  </ol>
  <ol start=4>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: I never knew about the start attribute for ol tags, so thanks for that.